# Joining two mysql queries containing time functions

Tags: mysql, join, date-format

I need to join the result of the next two queries:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( HOUR 
FROM (
TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , (

SELECT MIN( date_cmd ) 
FROM arc_commande_temp
WHERE id_cmd =  '6580' ) )
)
) AS HOURS

SELECT EXTRACT( MINUTE
FROM (
TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , (

SELECT MIN( date_cmd ) 
FROM arc_commande_temp
WHERE id_cmd =  '6580' ) )
)
) AS MINS
```

I know I have to use join them somehow but this Extract functions are giving me lots of problems. I have the next query that still works

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        MIN(date_cmd) AS HOURS
    FROM 
        arc_commande_temp
    WHERE 
        id_cmd = '6580') AS HOURS, 
    (SELECT 
        MIN(date_cmd) AS MINS
    FROM 
        arc_commande_temp
    WHERE 
        id_cmd = '6580') AS MINS
```

- it's not what I need but I'm trying to modify it to get what I want - but when I try to change something else in order to build the query I need... I get an error :-(

Thanks in advance and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (TIMEDIFF(NOW( ), (
        SELECT MIN(date_cmd) 
        FROM arc_commande_temp
        WHERE id_cmd =  '6580' 
    )))) AS HOURS
    ,
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (TIMEDIFF(NOW( ) , (
        SELECT MIN( date_cmd ) 
        FROM arc_commande_temp
        WHERE id_cmd =  '6580' 
    )))) AS MINS
```